# Loading a complete HTML Page in Modal Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, modalpopupextender

Ok so now it has been a day almost in searching about Modal box to display a complete **.HTML** file in Modal box rather opening it in new window or tab.

More precisely:

```
<a href="ajax.html" rel="modal:open">example</a>
```

This **ajax.html** file should open in "modal box" in the same window.

How can I acheive it through anchor tag?

I have searched thoroughly but found no good solution except this [one](http://kylefox.ca/jquery-modal/examples/index.html)(Example#4). This works on site but doesn't work when I download it.

.

P.S: I do not want to use **iframe**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few different ways to do this, but the best way is to use an AJAX request to the page using jQuery:

```
$.post("ajax.html", function(data){

    $("#myModalDiv").html(data).fadeIn();

});
```

Then to bind this to your anchor, assign it an ID and do this in your `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a#someId").on("click", function(){
        
        //Put the code from above here.

    });

});
```

---

#### Note that this will only work for files on the same domain.

If you want to use files on a different domain, you will have to use an iframe, therefore I cannot put this into a fiddle because there are no local files to pull on a fiddle.

Comment: `data` is what is returned by the `$.post()` request. It doesn't have to be called data, but that is what I use. You could do `$.post("ajax.html", function(sugar){});` and it would still work. So data essentially contains the contents of "ajax.html" since it is an HTML file. If you were to post to a PHP page, it would be whatever is echoed by the PHP page, including `echo` calls, `var_dumps`, errors, and HTML.

Comment: Whatever you want them to be. It could be empty.

Answer (score -1):

You can use bootstrap for the thing you want to do.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Check out the modal section.

Comment: If you mean Bootstrap's remote option for modals, they clearly state on the page you link to: "This option is deprecated since v3.3.0 and will be removed in v4. We recommend instead using client-side templating or a data binding framework, or calling jQuery.load yourself."